# How to get the binary data from a pdf and send back as response

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, response, octet-stream

I created a PDF of a website using puppeteer from a link provided by the client, and now I need to send back as response the stream code/ octet stream / binary data of this pdf, I am unsure how to do that can someone help me

I have the PDF stored locally in the same folder as my js file

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? Just google *upload file with javascript* and look at one of those.

Comment: Are you asking what "Content-Type:" you need in the return HTTP headers or something else?

Comment: @BarryCarter I am not sure how to send back the file as an octet stream, I suppose the content type is application/octet-stream right? I saw this code that uses Express.js but I use KOA so its not exactly working https://newbedev.com/javascript-how-to-send-application-octet-stream-express-code-example#:~:text=how%20to%20send%20application%2Foctet-stream%20%2B%20express%20code%20example,next%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20res.setHeader%28%27Content-Type%27%2C%20%27application%2Foctet-stream%27%29%3B%20res.sendFile%28%27%2Ffile%2Fto%2Fbe%2Fdownloaded.ext%27%29%3B%20res.status%28200%29%3B%20%7D%29%3B

Comment: Wouldn't the file be of type applicatoin/pdf?

Comment: @asdf3.14159 thats the thing I want it to be sent to the client as binary stream, help

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
response.body = fs.readFileSync("path/to/file.pdf");
```

in KOA.

This will automatically send the pdf file as an application/octet-stream.